# Continuity of function differential at a point where it's differentiable

Tags: derivatives, continuity

My textbook states: if f(x) is differentiable at x=a does not imply f'(a) is continuous. Isn't that wrong? Aren't non-differentiable points caused by discontinuities in f'(x)?

Edit: The textbook also used the function the first comment specifies. It's  $x^2 sin(\frac{1}{x})$ when x$\neq$0 and 0 at x=0. Here's the first part of the function, graphed using geogebra;

[image]

Clearly, it's continuous at x=0, so the example seems not to hold.

Comment: Let $f(x)=x^{2}\sin (\frac 1 x)$ for $x \neq 0, f(0)=0$. $f'$ is not continuous at $0$ though $f'(0)=0$.

Comment: @Kavi Added the graph of the function to the question; it seems to be continuous.

Comment: $f'$ is not continuous at $x = 0$.  [This graph should make it  geometrically clear](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gqtudpnrjo) . $f'(x)$ oscillates as $x \to 0$ and the limit does not exist.